# Loop over files of same length and add their column respectively

Tags: c

I have a directory that contains `Nfiles` text files called `myfile_i.txt` (with `i` and integer).

Each text file contains 2 columns (let's call them `x` and `y`) and `Nsteps` rows of floating numbers.

I would like to loop over all the files in the directory and do the following computation in C:

```
while [condition to go through all files called myfile_i.txt in the directory]
{
    for (ii= istart;ii<Nsteps; i++) // with istart>=0 and istart<Nsteps otherwise error
    {
        dsq[ii]=(x[ii]-x[istart])*(x[ii]-x[istart])+(y[ii]-y[istart])*(y[ii]-y[istart]);
    }
}
```

where `istart` is an input parameter (integer) that I choose as a starting point in terms of iteration (or if you will, time steps).

Then at the end I would need to devide this result (which I believe it a column vector) by the number of steps (basically, `Nsteps-istart`).

I used to do something like this in Matlab but I have lots of these large files and loading them all and computing this is too slow for my computer, this is why I want to use (and learn) C.

What should my program look like in order to accomplish this computation?

Comment: Are all the files in the same folder?

Comment: yes all files are in the same folder.

Comment: I could offer a solution in Python - C, is not my programming flavour at the moment - Would that suffice?

Comment: How big roughly are all the files together?

Comment: I have actually done it in Matlab and I am always happy to learn more Python, but I really believe it would be best in C. Also I would like to learn this type of data management in C.

Comment: My files are of ~ 120Mb each, ~1e6-1e8 lines each.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I have several folders, each of ~62Gb and containing ~200 txt files `my file_i.txt`. (each folder is a different set of parameters for my computation and all `.txt` files within a given folder differ by some randomness in another parameter, while sharing the value of the other parameters.) Overall I have 5 folders of ~62Gb folders each containing ~200, 120Mb `.txt` files.

Comment: I guess the most crucial thing for me right now is to know how to iterate on the name of the `.txt` files and to load their content while adding it up one after the other... @leopardxpreload

Comment: That part is not hard, but...  If your overhead is all in loading Gigabytes of information from the disk, Matlab and C will perform very similar.  A different question I guess is What is too slow?

Comment: Too slow is of the order of hours... at least on my 6y-o laptop. Also I would like to run this computation on my datasets directly on the (distant) computation cluster instead of downloading all the data (not enough disc space) on my laptop and running a Matlab code for ages on my old laptop... Thank you for your help